# animation rendering not working in blender

Tags: rendering, animation, armature

The animation works but when I launch a render does not appear. The only thing that appears is the character in the base position.
here is the result when I run the rendering of the animation
thank you[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that armature modifier is enabled for rendering:

[image]

Comment: thanks
that was good
good day